# How do I generate a smaller DFT result?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, downsampling

I have a very large input that I'm Fourier-transforming. Currently, I transform the entire signal and then downsample the result. Although the transform of the large input is expensive, my results maintain full accuracy - before downsampling.

If I simply subsampled the signal being transformed, the frequencies would obviously be affected - thus the DFT result is not equal.

I know there are techniques to down-sample a signal while maintaining frequency - would I need to use something like this?

Would it even be worth downsampling the signal before doing an $O(n\log(n))$ DFT - perhaps the downsampling of the signal is slower than $O(n\log(n))$, so theres no benefit.

Would downsampling a signal before FFT result in better or worse accuracy-to-performance than doing a standard FFT and then downsampling the result?

Comment: Dependant on what you do the [pruned FFT](http://www.fftw.org/pruned.html) can help.

Comment: @BlackYasmin I need the whole output; so I don't think pruning is a relevant tool.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I generate a smaller DFT result?

that primarily depends on what you want to do with the result and what your specific requirements are

> Currently, I transform the entire signal and then downsample the result.

It would probably better to do a STFT (Short Time Fourier Transform). Pick a frequency resolution that you need and the associated FFT size, chop your signal up into overlapping frames, window and FFT each frame. That gives you time/frequency representation and you can do whatever statistics you want. If you just want the average power spectrum, take the energy average of the individual frame FFTs. That's probably a much better result than downsampling a large FFT (without smoothing it first)

> Would downsampling the signal before DFT result in a better or worse accuracy for my DFT?

It would be really bad. Downsampling by itself would result in massive aliasing. The only way to avoid that is to low-pass filter first, in which case you would loose most of the spectrum. That's really not the way to go here.

**UPDATE** This is probably easier to understand if we look at a specific example.

Let's say we have a signal that 16384 samples long  sampled at 16384 kHz, i.e. your frequency resolution is 1 Hz. Let's also assume that your signal is pure sine wave at 5000 kHz and you only need/can-afford a spectrum size of 1024

1. Full size FFT: you get one bin at 5kHz. All good
2. Full FFT + downsample: Let's say you take every 16th sample. 5000 is not an integer multiple of 16 so you miss the only bin with data in. You get all zeros: WRONG
3. Down-sample and then FFT: When down-sampling by 16 you reduce the sample rate to 1024 Hz. Your original signal is way above your new Nyquist Frequency so there is no way represent it. You can apply an anti-aliasing filter, but this will just remove the 5 kHz and you get an all zero result:WRONG. Or you just let it alias in which case you see a single line at 120 Hz. WRONG
4. STFT: you maintain the sample rate of 16 kHz but your frequency resolution is reduced to 16Hz. You see most of the energy in the 4092Hz and the 5008 Hz bin plus some skirts around that. That's not ideal, but the best you can do in this case

Comment: It's slower to do multiple little FFTs. So, this only decreases performance and also decreases accuracy

Comment: Would downsampling a signal before FFT result in better or worse accuracy-to-performance than doing a standard FFT and then downsampling the result?

Comment: Re your first comment: you are wrong on both accounts. Small FFTs are faster and STFT is probably the most accurate method given your constraints. That's why most people are doing it that way.
Re:second comment: I thought I answered that: downsampling in time is bad since you either get massive aliasing or loose most of your spectrum entirely.

Comment: Regarding your edit, subsampling is not the only form of downsampling. Using a more sensible method will not skip the bin e.g. an averaging method.

Comment: with STFT, you're doing multiple DFT's with their own errors, which will accumulate (to an error larger than with a single DFT) when you merge their results together.

Comment: Additionally, with STFT, you need to apply windowing in order to avoid edge artifacts - this itself reduces your accuracy even more.

Comment: Additionally, STFT reduces your lower-bound-frequency resolution, as you can only observe a small window (so can't analyse longer wavelengths)